# Graphite movingAverage of sum of hitcount

Tags: graphite, whisper

I'm trying to render a graphite chart that has the `movingAverage` of the `sum` of the `hitcount` of several different metrics. This target:

```
sum(hitcount(stats.ambrosia.flows.*.*.messages.success,"1minutes"))
```

works nicely:

[image: Rendered Graphite Chart]

I would expect that the `movingAverage` of that target:

```
movingAverage(sum(hitcount(stats.ambrosia.flows.*.*.messages.success,"1minutes")),15)
```

would work well, too:

[image: Invalid Graphite Chart]

However, I get the dreaded "No Data" image instead. Outputting JSON format doesn't provide useful info in this case either, unfortunately, returning simply `[]`.

How can I compute the moving average of the above sum in Graphite? I've tried the following without luck as well:

```
sum(hitcount(movingAverage(stats.ambrosia.flows.*.*.messages.success,15),"1minutes"))
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: can you query graphite with json output to see if there is really no data?

Comment: @kamaradclimber, I think I have. I used `&format=json` on the render endpoint, and the result to that call is `[]`, as I noted in my question. Is that what you meant? Regardless, thank you for the suggestion!

Answer (score 2):

Not sure which graphite version you're using, but following works for me on my environment (indented for readability):

```
movingAverage(
  summarize(
    sumSeries(stats.counters.*.app.elasticFacade.periodUsage.reads.*.count),
    "1minutes"
  ),
  15
)
```